# Ad serving has been disabled

Tags: android, google-play, admob, adsense

Any Admob and Adsense expert here?
I uploaded one of my application in play store about 7-8 months ago. In this application, ad serving works fine. But yesterday AdMob sent me an email explaining below issue. My application downloads videos from Facebook and it plays videos.

Which AdMob policy is violated by this application. There are hundreds of applications are available in the Play Store which has the same concept. How could I solve this issue and How could I enable ad serving in my application again. My application is downloaded more than 15k times So I can't ignore my application.

"Violation explanation

Issue ID#: 124267292

As stated in our program policies, we may not show Google ads on pages with little to no value and/or excessive advertising until changes are made. This includes but is not limited to:

-Mirroring, framing, scraping or rewriting of content from other sources without adding value

-Pages that don’t follow our Webmaster quality guidelines."

Comment: `excessive advertising` are you doing it?

Comment: What is `excessive advertising`? Could you please explain?

Comment: Showing too many ads inside the app!

Answer (score 0):

have you got email account disable related?, they send email with bit of Violation information and also send one time appeal form link for continue account. you should appeal with all information, they reply in 24 hour and if they found if was not violation then enable your account.

Comment: Yes, They have sent me an email, I have maintained a violation explanation in my question. How can I fix this issue in my application and Republish my application?